# To write a Scala program to convert the given date & time to GMT based on airport code

Tags: scala, datetime

Help me to write a  Scala program to convert the given date & time to GMT based on airport code.
Input will have 3 Arguments

For E:g  For Chennai
**2021-07-26 ,00:23, MAA**  (3 Arguments)

Output will be two arguments
**2021-07-25,  18:54**

The Chennai time 26-07-2021 00:23 equals to the GMT time 25-07-2021 18:54.

Comment: that should be `GMT time 25-07-2021 18:53`

Comment: Also, since this has nothing to do with apache spark. Removing those tags.

Answer (score 1):

You will first require a mapping of `AirportCode -> TimeZone` (which can give you UTC offset) or directly `AirportCode -> UTC Offset`.

Then you can use this timezone/offset to convert the given date-time to GMT.

Here is a file containing Airport Code to timezone mapping for 20,000+ airports - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opentraveldata/opentraveldata/master/opentraveldata/optd_por_public.csv

You can process this file and create that map of `airport-code` to `time-zone`.

Once your have that map, (lets name it `airportCodeToTimezoneMap`), you can use following code.

```scala
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.{LocalDateTime, ZoneId}

val airportCodeToTimezoneMap = Map("MAA" -> "Asia/Kolkata")

val inputString = "2021-07-26, 00:23, MAA"

val Array(date, time, airportCode) = inputString.split(",").map(_.strip())

// prepare ZoneId's

val airportTimezoneNameOption = airportCodeToTimezoneMap.get(airportCode)

val airportTimezoneName = airportTimezoneNameOption.get

val airportZoneId = ZoneId.of(airportTimezoneName)

val gmtZoneId = ZoneId.of("GMT")

//

val dateTimeString = s"${date}T${time}"

val airportLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)

val airportZonedDateTime = airportLocalDateTime.atZone(airportZoneId)

val gmtZonedDateTime = airportZonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(gmtZoneId)
// gmtZonedDateTime: java.time.ZonedDateTime = 2021-07-25T18:53Z[GMT]
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of MAP if i want to create as a JSON and use it .Please tell how to read from JSON  file  instead of MAP .

Comment: {
      "airportCode": "AAL",
      "zoneId": "Europe/Copenhagen"
    },
    {
      "airportCode": "AAM",
      "zoneId": "Africa/Johannesburg"
    },    Like this if I am  keeping in a JSON file . How can i read and use it Instead of creating all the possible Key values in MAP itself

Comment: A json file is just a file, which can be said to contain a string. Although, here this string is representing a json but you can not use it as anything other than a String. You can not just query data from a String. Think of it this way, a file is like a book, it has the content but you can not find particular content in a book. For being able to find content you need an index. For example - A dictionary is indexed using alphabetical order, hence you can find required words in it. So, for this use-case you need something like a `Map`. So, you can read your json file to create this `Map`.